# How can I use type traits to compare only the first template parameter in class that has multiple parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits, static-assert

So I have this function, `GetProperty()`, that is defined like the following:

```
template<typename T>
void GetProperty(T & val)
```

I want this to accept three possible values: `bool`, `int`, and a string class that has two template parameters. The string class, let's call it `StringT`, looks something like this:

```
template<typename CharType, size_t Size>
class StringT
```

I would like to be able to pass an instance of `StringT` to `GetProperty()` so that it only checks the `CharType` and allows any value for `Size`. For example, both of these calls should work without any extra specialization:

```
StringT<char, 512> str1;
GetProperty(str1);

StringT<char, 1024> str2;
GetProperty(str2);
```

The current implementation I have looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
void GetProperty(T & val)
{
    // Trying to use static_assert to only allow StringT values in the default implementation.
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, StringT<char, 512>>::value, "FAILED");

    // Do stuff
}

template<>
void GetProperty<bool>(bool & val)
{
    // Do stuff
}

template<>
void GetProperty<int>(int & val)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work since it only allows a `StringT<char, 512>` type to be specified. Is there any way to ignore the `512` template parameter and have it accept any value for `Size`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option #1

Provide a separate function overload for each type, so that you can accept any `StringT<char, ?>` in one of the overloads:

```
template <size_t N>
void GetProperty(StringT<char, N>& val) {}

void GetProperty(bool val) {}

void GetProperty(int val) {}
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78ff23aa22d4e55a)

#### Option #2

Write your own type-trait:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename S, typename C>
struct IsStringT : std::false_type {};

template <typename C, size_t Size>
struct IsStringT<StringT<C, Size>, C> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
void GetProperty(T & val)
{
    static_assert(IsStringT<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type, char>{}, "FAILED");
}

template <>
void GetProperty<bool>(bool & val) {}

template <>
void GetProperty<int>(int & val) {}
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b881bf598831e0a)

Comment: That's really sweet. I think there's an error though. Should the assert look like this? static_assert(IsStringT<T, char>::value, "FAILED");

Comment: @Shenjoku in an older compiler you probably need the `IsStringT<T, char>::value` syntax

Comment: Ah, alright. This seems to be working with that change. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the `StringT` class, you can add an extra field to the public section, something to the effect of:

```
using char_t = CharType;
```

Then you can update your static assert to:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<typename T::char_t, char>::value, "FAILED");
```

In this case, any class with a `char_t` defined could be used here.

On the other hand, if you know that `GetProperty` will always be used with a `StringT`, you can change it's outermost definition to:

```
template<typename CharType, size_t Size>
void GetProperty(StringT<CharType,Size> & val)
```

...and then you'll have direct access to `CharType`.